# How to enable color options in ConEmu, similar to bash terminal?

Tags: conemu

In Linux bash terminal we can enable color.

Is it possible to achieve the same for ConEmu?

Answer (score 10):

Seems to me, your question is incorrect. You need to enable color in your console application, but not in ConEmu, because it is terminal, but not a shell. Refer to your shell/application manuals. For example, `ls` has special switch.

[image: ls --color]

There are also ANSI sequences, ConEmu supports them - you must enable two options (ATM they are on the Features page of Settings dialog)

- Inject ConEmuHk
- ANSI X3.64

[image: Enabling colors in ConEmu]

Of course, your application must be able to output ANSI codes to console. If they not - ConEmu can't do anything with them, because it is terminal, but not a shell.

Comment: I Thanks a lot for your time and helping out of this confusion.

Comment: This post is very helpful, but I still can't get mine to work. I've tried with cmd.exe as the underlying shell in the startup section, as well as zsh for windows and tccle.exe but when I execute "ls --color" provided by Gnuwin 32's coreutils package I just get ansi escape codes in the output. Even when I use the Git Bash console I just get ansi codes (whereas git commands via sh.exe show color). Any idea why?

Comment: @Sridhar-Sarnobat if you get raw ansi escape codes, why not to enable them in ConEmu? [wiki](https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/AnsiEscapeCodes#ANSI_sequences_processing_requirements)

Comment: Appearance -> ANSI X3.64 / xterm 256 colors was already checked, and so was Miscellaneous Options -> Inject ConEmuHk. But I still get escape codes in the output. Is there soemthing else I need to do?

Comment: Update to preview build at least.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked in the [Options dialog](https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/Settings#Colors).

[image]

Comment: Yes I tried that earlier too.

I am looking for something like for example, dir are in different color if I press ls command

Comment: The color scemes are important if you see **wrong colors**, e.g. the green is displayed as red/yellow. I also prefer <Ubuntu> style.

Comment: yeah I thought it wasn't working - and then I went to this page and changed to another scheme. The default conemu hides my coloring for some reaosn.

Comment: the `ubuntu` scheme is nice for example